# Update info record in purchase orders

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I have a requirement that consists of, every time the user changes a unit of measure of a material using `MM02`, I have to change the info record. After this, I have to select all purchase orders that contain this material and that are not delivered or partially delivered and update Order unit <--> SKU.

The first part is done, that is update the info record (`EINA` table), but now I'm stuck in the second part of the requirement.

I will show what the user manually does to achieve that.

First, the user enters in `MM02` and makes the change on the field marked in red color:

[image: MM02]

After he saves, changes are reflected in the info record (`EINA` table) `ME13` transaction.

[image: ME13]

Now, to have this done in the purchase order, the user enters `ME22N` and opens a purchase order. On the items, he locates that one containing the material changed before, go to info record field, erase its content and press enter and the field Order **unit <--> SKU** is updated. Then, the user enters the info record again and saves the purchase order.

Here is the field before the user makes changes to the item.

[image: ME22N]

Now the user locates the info record field.

[image: Info record]

Clear the field and press Enter.

[image: Info record]

Now how you can see, the field **Order unit <--> SKU** was updated.

[image: Field updated]

Now, I ask you guys if there is a way to do the the same thing the user does using `ME22N` but using `BAPI_PO_CHANGE`?

I would not like do this using a batch input because `ME22N` is an enjoy and this kind of transactions do not work well with batch input. Additionally, in the old transaction `ME22`, this particular field (info record) is not open for input.

I appreciate any help.

Best regards.

Ronaldo S. Vieira

Comment: BAPI/FM and batch input are the most common update techniques. Have you tried using BAPI_PO_CHANGE and got any error? by the way, BAPIMEPOITEM structure has INFO_REC field that you can use.